# Multi-level navigation using bootstrap in laravel 5

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 as my framework.

I have a categories table like this:

[image]

I want to make it as a bootstrap menu with multi-level if the `parent_id = id`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">        
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            @foreach( $category as $cat )
                @if( $cat->id === $cat->parent_id)
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="{{ url( '/category', Safeurl::make( $cat->name ) ) }}" data-toggle="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">{{ $cat->name }}
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url( '/category', [Safeurl::make( $cat->name ), Safeurl::make( $cat->name )] ) }}"></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                @else
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ url( '/category', Safeurl::make( $cat->name ) ) }}">{{ $cat->name }}</a>
                    </li>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But this results is, I get the output as 1 below the other.

I want that if the `parent_id = id`, it should show the sub category next to the that particular id.

For example, in the current example, `id = 6` has the `parent_id = 4`, that means, the bootstrap menu should show the sub-category link next to the `Clothing`.

**UPDATE 1**:

After the answer submitted, I cannot display the sub category.

Here's the code for that:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        @foreach( $category as $cat )
            <li @if($cat->childs->count()) class="dropdown" @endif>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" @if( $cat->childs->count() ) class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" @endif>
                    {{ $cat->name }}
                    @if( $cat->childs->count() )
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    @endif
                </a>
            @if( $cat->childs->count() )
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    @foreach( $cat->childs as $child )
                        <a href="{{url('/category', [Safeurl::make($cat->name), Safeurl::make($child->name)])}}">
                            {{ $child->name }}
                        </a>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Can anybody please help me out ?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is add a relation in your model

```
public function childs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

In your controller select just category where parent_id==0

And in your view you can ask for children:

```
@foreach( $category as $cat )
    <li @if($cat->childs->count()) class="dropdown" @endif>
        <a href="{{ url( '/category', Safeurl::make( $cat->name ) ) }}" @if($cat->childs->count()) class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" @endif>{{ $cat->name }} @if($cat->childs->count()) <span class="caret"></span> @endif</a>
        @if($cat->childs->count())
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
             @foreach($cat->childs as $child)
                 <li><a href="{{ url( '/category', [Safeurl::make( $child->name ), Safeurl::make( $child->name )] ) }}"></a></li>
             @endforeach
             </ul>
        @endif
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: In my controller, I have `$category = Category::all();`.. When I tried your code, it returned me nothing.. I mean the categories cannot be seen at all..

Comment: Did you added the childs relation in your category model?

Comment: try $category = Category::where('parent_id', '=', '0')->with('childs')->get();

Comment: Also enable debug, because i write it fast and can be an error in code

Comment: and try using $category->childs->count (with no ()) on view

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$childs

Comment: Well, instead of `$category->childs->count()` it should be `$cat->childs->count()`.. But this resulted in another bug, if I click on it, it takes me to that page, I do not want to click, instead, on hover, it should show the child categories...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75977/discussion-between-maztch-and-user3514160).

Comment: Will your code show the sub categories on hovering the parent category ?? Just curious..

Comment: Your code is not showing the child category at all.. Neither on click nor on hover.. Kindly help me out with this..